# How to add glossary to table of contents as clickable entry?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperlink, glossary

i have the following question:
I just made a glossary and added it to the table of content with

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}
```

Then i was missing a clickable referencee to take me to the glossary instantly so i added

```
\chapter*{Glossar\markboth{Glossar}}
```

Which i saw is part of the abbreviations page that i took from a template.

Now i can see it in the toc, although if i click on the hyperlink, it takes me to the chapter before (abbreviations). How can i change this behaviour to a clickable reference so that i land at the glossary?

MRE:

```
\chapter*{Glossar\markboth{Glossar}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}

\newglossaryentry{example}
{
    name=example,
    description={this is an example description}
}

\printglossaries
```

I'd be grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}`, load `glossaries` after `hyperref` if you are using `hyperref` for hyperlinks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! I was missing the \usepackage[toc]{glossaries} and instead used \usepackage[automake]{glossaries} - your solution works perfect in my case.